# Load Balancer and Proxy for Meteor not passing to 127.0.0.1 - Too Many Redirects?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, vps, meteor

I have the following setup, but see 302 Moved Temporarily when I curl the load balancer. In a browser it reports Too Many Redirects:

- 1 load balancer with SSL
- 2 web servers

I request https://www.domain.com and I get back a 302 with the same URL in it (see edit below). Here's the server setup:

**Server 1 - IP eg 1.1.1.1**
Nginx configured as a load balancer which handles SSL and redirects http to https:

```
server_tokens off; # for security-by-obscurity: stop displaying nginx version
upstream www_backend {
    ip_hash;
    server 2.2.2.2:80;
    server 3.3.3.3:80;
}
# this section is needed to proxy web-socket connections
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}
# HTTP
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com; # the domain on which we want to host the application.
    # redirect non-SSL to SSL
    location / {
        rewrite     ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/www.domain.com/server.pem; # full path to SSL certificate and CA certificate concatenated together
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/www.domain.com/server.key; # full path to SSL key
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers       on;
    ssl_protocols                   TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-R blah blah';
    # config to enable HSTS(HTTP Strict Transport Security) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security
    # to avoid ssl stripping https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL_stripping#SSL_stripping
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://www_backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
    }
}
```

**Web Server 1 - IP eg 2.2.2.2**
Nginx configured as proxy, listens on port 80 and passes on to port 8080:

```
server_tokens off; # for security-by-obscurity: stop displaying nginx version
# this section is needed to proxy web-socket connections
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}
# HTTP
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name www.domain.com;

    root /var/www/nginx/html;

    location /200.html {
        rewrite ^ /200.html break;
    }

    # pass all requests to Meteor
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; # preserve client IP
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; # allow websockets
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

        # this setting allows the browser to cache the application in a way compatible with Meteor
        # on every application update the name of CSS and JS file is different, so they can be cache infinitely (here: 30 days)
        # the root path (/) MUST NOT be cached
        if ($uri != '/') {
            expires 30d;
        }
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location /50x.html{
        root /var/www/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

I've included some static HTML pages to test that the web server is reached.

Meteor application, listens on local port 8080:

```
export PORT=8080
# this allows Meteor to figure out correct IP address of visitors
export HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT=1
# The domain name as configured previously as server_name in nginx
export ROOT_URL=http://www.domain.com
#Start Meteor
exec node /var/www/blah/main.js >> /var/log/blah/meteor.log
```

Web server 2 is configured similarly.

If I ssh into web1 and curl meteor, it responds as expected: curl http:127.0.0.1:8080

If I curl the test HTML page from my dev machine it responds as expected: curl https://www.domain.com/200.html

However if I curl the root from my dev it responds with nothing at all: curl https://www.domain.com

Hitting https://www.domain.com in Chrome show a Too Many Redirect error. As I'm hitting https, not http, I don't understand how these redirects could be caused.

I have A+ rating for the SSL from Qualsys. I've run sudo nginx -t on all server and the nginx files are correct.

I've created a symbolic link from /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www.domain.com -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/www.domain.com

I've reloaded Nginx: sudo nginx -s reload

**Edit**
BTW - I previously removed /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default and /etc/nginx/sites-available/default at the recommendation of another ServerFault user.

**Edit**
Here's the verbose response from curl:

```
* About to connect() to www.domain.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 1.1.1.1...
* connected
* Connected to www.domain.com (1.1.1.1) port 443 (#0)
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: CN=www.domain.com
*    start date: 2016-03-14 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2019-03-14 23:59:59 GMT
*    subjectAltName: www.domain.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=GeoTrust Inc.; CN=Blah Blah 
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
> Host: www.domain.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Server: nginx
< Date: Mon, 28 Mar 2016 05:52:35 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://www.domain.com/
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.domain.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

I checked the Nginx access log on the webserver and seems to confirm that it's the webserver sending the 302, not the load balancer:

```
[28/Mar/2016:01:56:28 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5"
```

So in summary, the load balancer seems to be successfully passing the SSL call from 443 to the webservers 80. The meteor service is running on web 1&2 and successfully reponding to local port 8080 requests. It seems that the web servers proxy is not passing port 80 requests on to port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

On the web server I changed the scheme line to force https:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

`sudo reboot` and it worked.